# Find element in 2d array closest to a specified value within a certain section of that array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to calculate the gradient of the linear section at the beginning of a line graph that I have plotted from a 2D array. Instead of looking through the array myself to find the values that I need to calculate this gradient, I want code that will do this for me. For example, if it looks like the linear section ends at around 200MPa (The black line here)

[image]

I want the code to find the stress value and corresponding index that is nearest to 200 in the first section of the graph (first 2% on the x axis)

The code I have written so far finds the closest value but includes the whole array so gives points near the end of the curve occasionally

```
def find_nearest(array, value):
    diff = np.abs(array - value)
    idx = np.where(diff == diff.min())
    return idx


valueA = 200
print(find_nearest(TensA, valueA))
```

Comment: Can't you just take the first index returned and ignore the rest?

Comment: Taking just the first index would have the same effect depending on the sampling rate (if the plot had a point closer to 200 in the slope instead of that at 2%).

Comment: You could discard the edges (if that's okay for your application: `TensA[start:end]`) or write a more elaborate algorithm with some gradient threshold, checking the neighborhood or even some apply high-pass filter convolution (wild guess, it really depends on your application).

Comment: @TimRoberts That is true but because the data for the graph was obtained experimentally, it would be more accurate to look at a larger portion of the linear section

Comment: @vbarboza I could discard the edges however, this would require looking through the array myself for each plot to find where a suitable place to end it would be, which is what I wish to avoid

Comment: Then how will you decide which point you want?  If you can describe the criteria, you can code it.